# android send voice notification to user

Tags: android, notifications

I have written a background service to find user's location. Now i want to send a voice notification to user when his location is changed.
I have wrote the code for determining the location change and sending simple push notification, now can anyone help me with making it voice notification or how to write a voice notification code or is there any third party library by which we send the voice notification to user.
Help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes finally i got it in very easy way and a complete solution.

```
private TextToSpeech myTTS;   // Define the TTS objecy
private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

//write the following code in oncreate method or whereever you want to use this
{ 
    myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
    checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    speakWords("Pass the String here"); 
}

private void speakWords(String speech) {
    //speak straight away
    //myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    System.out.println(speech + " TTSTTTS");
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE, null);
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example
[link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/), whose part you may need is pasted here.

```
private TextToSpeech myTTS;

Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

speakWords(words);  //call this function with the string you want as voice

        //speak the user text
private void speakWords(String speech) {
        //speak straight away
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
    //act on result of TTS data check
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else {
                //no data - install it now
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}
    //setup TTS  and don't forget to implement OnInitListener interface to use this method
public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        //check for successful instantiation
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    }
    else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use android text to speech api [see reference here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your notification method (where `notificationManager.notify(0, notification);` is called), add the following:

```
try {
        Uri ring_uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ring_uri);
        r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
        // Error playing sound
}
```

This will make a notification sound whenever you push notification.

Comment: Hey, can i customize this sound mean, right now its only notification i want it to say particular string.
Please reply ASAP

Comment: If you have voice files of each voice you want to play you can use this but I think it is not the case in your problem. You should use TextToSpeech class